# Local hash initialization in perl module results in empty hash

Tags: perl, module, initialization, local-variables

When I initialize a local hash (using "my") in a perl module, the hash appears to be empty from within module functions.

Here is the perl module code:

```
package Test;

use 5.014002;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => [ qw(test) ]
);

our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );

our @EXPORT = qw(

);

our $VERSION = '0.01';

my %h = ( "1" => "one" );

BEGIN
{
}

sub test
{
    my $a = shift;
    print $Test::h{$a} . "\n";
}

1;
__END__
```

Here, test sees an empty hash.

If instead I declare the hash first, but initialize it within BEGIN, then it works fine. Here is the modified code:

```
package Test;

use 5.014002;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw('import');

our %EXPORT_TAGS = (
    'all' => [ qw(test) ]
);

our @EXPORT_OK = ( @{ $EXPORT_TAGS{'all'} } );

our @EXPORT = qw(

);

our $VERSION = '0.01';

my %h;

BEGIN
{
    %Test::h = ( "1" => "one" );
}

sub test
{
    my $a = shift;
    print $Test::h{$a} . "\n";
}

1;
__END__
```

Additionally, if I declare the hash using "our" instead, then it works fine in both cases.

What am I missing?

Comment: I tried removing the declaration "my %h;" from the second example, and the code still compiled and worked! This means that %h and %Test::h are two different variables. I am assuming that %Test::h inside the BEGIN block in the 2nd example is auto-declared by Perl, *even though* use strict is requested.

Comment: `Test::h` and `my %h` are totally different variables. You should be getting a warning similar to this `Name "Test::h" used only once: possible typo at test.pl line 25.` with your first example. Are you not seeing that? Note: this works fine with `our` because `our %h = ....` is an alias for `%Test::h = ...`.

Comment: In the first example I get a warning: Use of uninitialized value within %Test::h in concatenation (.) or string at Test.pm line 30. In the second example I get no warnings, even though I have not declared Test::h using my, our or state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`our`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html) makes a *lexical* alias to a *dynamically scoped package variable*, the kind that can be referenced by a $Fully::Qualified::name.

[`my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) makes a *lexically scoped* variable, the kind that can be referenced just by $name.

Drawing from [@Schwern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern)'s comment, by "lexical" we mean limited to the enclosing block and any subsequent nested blocks, but *not* visible inside other blocks (e.g., an elsewhere-defined subroutine called from within the block that declares `my $lexical_var` cannot see that variable).

So, in your code, `my %h` is a variable lexically scoped to the implicit block of its enclosing file (Test.pm?).  `our %h`, on the other hand, is a lexical *alias* to a completely different variable, specifically to a package (global) variable whose fully qualified name is `%Test::h`.  In both examples your `sub test` queries the package variable by its fully qualified name.  But only in the second example do you assign any values to that variable.

(You didn't ask about it specifically, but [`local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/local.html) dynamically scopes the given package variable to the enclosing file, block, or eval.  You use the adjective "local" a few times in your post in a way that's inconsistent with what it means as a perl keyword.)

Comment: Might want to explain what lexical scoping is.  I usually say its a variable that exists only within its block (and any nested blocks) and nowhere else.  There's an implied block around the whole file.

Comment: So, now I have another issue. I declared "my %h = ();" before then BEGIN block. Then I added a value to the hash inside the BEGIN block (BEGIN { $h{"1"} = "one"; }). Then I print $h{"1"} from within the test function, and I get error: Use of uninitialized value within %h in concatenation (.) or string at /tmp/Test.pm line 31.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, if instead I declare my %h before the BEGIN block, and then do BEGIN { %h = ( "1" => "one" ); }, it works fine.

Comment: And to make this even more confusing, if I declare my %h before the BEGIN block (instead of my %h = ();), and then do $h{"1"} = "one"; inside the BEGIN block, it works! So initializing the hash outside of the BEGIN block has some weird side-effect that I do not understand.

Comment: @kounoupis, okay.  If [this entry from _perlfaq7_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-lexical-%28static%29-scoping%3f-Between-local%28%29-and-my%28%29%3f) doesn't help, you need to find a good perl scoping tutorial.  Maybe ask [the venerable monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/)

Comment: The answer to my comment is that the BEGIN block is executed before everything else, and the subsequent declaration of "my %h = ();" obliterates the hash already initialized within BEGIN earlier. I don't think this has to do with scoping. Maybe what I am asking in the comment is unclear.

Answer (score -4):

Ouch - what are you trying to do?
Is there a reason for this 'use 5.014002;'?
I mean it is cool if you trying for some old school stuff - I just got criticized on this site for doing old school perl.  But if you're learning maybe you want to do new stuff?

The OO perl I do with packages and such are below. 
Anyway.

```
package myModule;

sub new
{
   $class = shift;
   my $self = {};
   bless $self, $class;

   return $self;
}

sub someMethod
{
   my $self = shift;
   $self->{some} = "value";

   return $self;
}

1;
```

Comment: I downvoted because this doesn't answer the problems the OP is having.  They've misunderstood lexical vs global variables, a very important and basic thing to know in Perl.  Telling them to use objects isn't going to fix that and is likely to cause more confusion.  And 5.14.2 is only 3 years old and hardly relevant to the question.  Everything in your answer has been available since Perl 5.0.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding `use 5.014002`, which refers to Perl 5.14.2, not Perl 5.0.1 or something like that. See the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) for `use`: "In the peculiar `use VERSION` form, `VERSION` may be...a positive decimal fraction such as 5.006, which will be compared to `$]`" According to [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$]), `$]` is "The version + patchlevel / 1000 of the Perl interpreter."